# Determine the smallest disc in which all the eigen values of a given matrix lie

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let , $$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&-2&3&-2\\1&1&0&3\\-1&1&1&-1\\0&-3&1&1\end{matrix}\right]$$Which of the following is the **smallest disc** in $\mathbb C$  which contains all eigen values of $A$.

1. $|z-1|\le 7$
2. $|z-1|\le 6$
3. $|z-1|\le 4$.

Characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^4-4x^3+21x^2-48x+46$. From this computing eigen values is very difficult in hand. Without computing eigen values how we can detect the required interval ?

Does there any other process??

Comment: By Gershgorin circle theorem all eigen values lie in $|z-1|\leq 7.$

Comment: Or, consider the $1$-norm (or the $\infty$-norm) of $A-I$.

Comment: @@Suhail ) I think you miss the point ' smallest disc '...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's an application of the Gershgorin Theorem:
The theorem states that the eigenvalues are bounded in the union of the regions:
\begin{equation}
K_i=\left\{ |z-a_{ii}|<\underset{{\scriptscriptstyle i\neq j}}{\sum|a_{ij}|}\right\} 
\end{equation}

Here we have:
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&-2&3&-2\\1&1&0&3\\-1&1&1&-1\\0&-3&1&1\end{matrix}\right]$$
The circles are all centered on value 1 since all $a_{ii}=1$ so summing horizontally line by line you would obtain the following restriction on the eigenvalues:
$$K_1=\left\{|z-1|< |-2|+|3|+|-2|=7 \right\} $$
$$K_2=\left\{|z-1|<  4 \right\}$$
$$K_3=\left\{|z-1|<  3\right\}$$
$$K_4=\left\{|z-1|<  4\right\}$$
The union of all $K_i$ is $K_1$. So $K=\left\{|z-1|<7 \right\}$ seems to be the minimum disc including all the eigenvalues. **But** since the eigenvalues are the same for the transpose of the matrix you can calculate again **watching for the columns instead of the rows** and obtain
$$|z-a_{ii}|< {\sum}|a_{ji}|$$ with $i \neq j$ and obtain as maximum radius
$$|z-1|< |-2|+|-3|+|1|=6$$
So **the correct answer is the $\bf (2)$** and all eigenvalues are included in $K=\left\{|z-1|<6 \right\}$

Comment: from where I got this question, found that the answer is "option (1)". I can't understand how ? Can you help me in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

*(Too long for a comment.)*

This looks like a trick question and I don't know the trick, but you may try the following approach. Let $B=A-I$. The characteristic polynomial of $B$ is $x^4 + 15x^2 - 14x + 16$. As $15x^2-14x+16>0$ over $\mathbb R$, $B$ has no real eigenvalues. Since $B$ has zero trace and nonreal eigenvalues of a real matrix must occur in conjugate pairs, it follows that
$$
x^4+15x^2-14x+16=(x^2-2ax+r^2)(x^2+2ax+R^2)
$$
where $a\ne0$ is the real part of one of the eigenvalues of $B$ and $r,R$ ( with $(0<|a|<r\le R$) are the moduli of the eigenvalues of $B$. By comparing coefficients of both sides, we get
\begin{cases}
R^2 + r^2 - 4a^2 = 15,\\
2a(R^2-r^2) = 14,\\
r^2R^2 = 16.
\end{cases}
Substitute the last two equations into the first, we get
$$
\left(\frac{16}{r^2} + r^2 - 15\right)\left(\frac{16}{r^2} - r^2\right)^2 = 196.
$$
If you can show that $r>1$, then we may conclude from $r^2R^2=16$ that $R<4$ and hence $(3)$ is the correct answer.

Comment: @@user1551))Firstly , the given answer is $(2)$ from where I collect the problem. Can you explain it by 'Gershgorin circle theorem' ?

Comment: Gershgorin only gives a bound.  It's not necessarily the best bound.  The question is poorly written.  As stated, the correct answer is "None of the above": the smallest is approximately $|z - .495567| < 3.833136671$.